# Copy value from one input and paste value into second input with each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to take what someone types into one text input and copy it into a second one. I am able to accomplish this, my problem is with the each function. These two input fields (side by side) repeat a couple times in a row and I need to have different values per row. You can see my issue in the fiddle.

Here's some example code:

HTML:

```
<div class="media">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-holder-one">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="input-holder-two">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="media">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-holder-one">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="input-holder-two">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.media .row').each(function(){

        $(this).find('.input-holder-one input').on('keyup', function(){
            $('.input-holder-two input').val($('.input-holder-one input').val());
        });
    });
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/p37s6k3c/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is using just the selector `$('.input-holder-two input')` and using  `.val()` on that will only set the `value` of the first element matched (*as the selector gets many elements*). You can solve this by using `$(this).find()` as you did to attach your event handler to get the element you want.

You can use `$(this).find(..)` to get those elements in the same way you attached the event handler:

```
$('.media .row').each(function(){
    var $holderOne = $(this).find('.input-holder-one input');
    var $holderTwo = $(this).find('.input-holder-two input');
    $holderOne.on('keyup', function(){
        $holderTwo.val($holderOne.val());
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/p37s6k3c/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It's your selectors that are bad.  You need to find the input that is in the same `.row`.

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".input-holder-one>input").keyup(function(e){
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.parents(".row").find(".input-holder-two>input").val($this.val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="media">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-holder-one">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="input-holder-two">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="media">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-holder-one">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="input-holder-two">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```